# fluentd remove keys dynamically

Tags: fluentd

I need to remove keys from json messages, pretty easy with **record_transformer** and **keep_keys** or **remove_keys**.
But the keys I want to remove are values from a specific key (ex: filter)

*input like:*

`{"message":"hello world!", "key1":"test1", "key2"="test2", "key3"="test3", "**filter**"="message,key3"}`

*want transformed into:*

`{"message":"hello world!", "key3"="test3"}`

I want the keep_keys parameter been dynamic for each messages.
How this can be achieve ? with just config or with plugin modification ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try with ruby based logic with record field for removal like below.

Example 1:
https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-record-modifier/issues/15

**Sample for ruby implementation:**

```
<filter kubernetes.**>
   @type record_transformer
   enable_ruby
   <record>
      log ${record["message"] or record["log"]}
   </record>
   remove_keys message
</filter>
```